# Jenkins Docker Cloud - Dynamic Agent Template Image

Tags: docker, jenkins, cloud

### Setup

I'm trying to setup a Jenkins CI pipeline:

1. A Jenkins Main node which manages the pipeline
2. A build node generates docker containers (Stage 1 & 2)
3. Another node runs these containers. These containers are launched by Jenkins using Docker remote API (Stage 3)

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5f39.png)

Here is the pipeline (truncated)

```
pipeline {
   agent {
      label 'Build'
   }
   options {
       skipDefaultCheckout()
   }
   stages {
      stage('1')
      {
         steps {
            sh script: "$WORKSPACE/jenkins/build_packages.sh", label: "Build Packages"
         }
      }
      stage('2')
      {
         steps {
            sh script: "$WORKSPACE/jenkins/build_container.sh", label: "Build Container"
         }
      }
      stage('3')
      {
         steps {
            script {
               for (def key in testsuites.keySet())
               {
                  def testsuite = key
                  executions[testsuite] = {
                     node('Docker-Test')
                     {
                        execute_testsuite(testsuite, testsuites[testsuite])
                     }
                  }
               }
               parallel(executions)
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Stage 2 will push to a remote registry the built image. In stage 3, this image is used. This is working perfectly.

### Problem

My problem is if the CI is triggered by two different developpers at the same time, then the image may change during execution of testsuites...

What i would like to do is push a different image (e.g. using git hash as docker tag) and use that image in Stage 3. And probably use the internal Jenkins function to build the image and push it instead of my own scripts.

But the image is set within the Docker Cloud - Agent Template configuration (see in screen capture below). Is there a way to modify this from within the pipeline ?

[Docker Cloud - Agent Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FgoZ.png)

This seems to be something possible at least using Kubernetes:

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049905312-Dynamically-selecting-the-docker-image-for-a-downstream-Pipeline-using-Kubernetes-Pod-Templates